# Failing tests: cannot read properties of undefined(reading local) solana devnet

Tags: typescript, solana, anchor-solana

Hello i am trying to test my first file in anchor and it keeps giving this error,
error i got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/benny/mycalcdapp/tests/mycalcdapp.ts:6:36)
    at Object.create (/home/benny/mycalcdapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:148:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/home/benny/mycalcdapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:42:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/benny/mycalcdapp/tests/mycalcdapp.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/benny/mycalcdapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
```

.ts file for test:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const anchor = require('@project-serum/anchor');
const { SystemProgram } = anchor.web3;

describe('mycalcdapp', () => {
  const provider = anchor.Provider.local();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const calculator = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const program = anchor.workspace.mycalcdapp;

  it('creates a calculator', async () => {
    await program.rpc.create('Welocme to solana', {
      accounts: {
        calculator: calculator.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        system_program: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [calculator],
    });
    const account = await program.account.calculator.fetch(
      calculator.publicKey
    );
    assert.ok(account.greeting === 'Welcome to solana');
  });
});
```

i have seen another similar stackoverflow postv about not being able to read rpc but it was not answered either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue in your code was the name of your dapp.

```
 const program = anchor.workspace.mycalcdapp;
```

your workspace name should be initialized with capital letter

```
 const program = anchor.workspace.Mycalcdapp;
```

also inside "it" block `welcome` is misspelled

```
await program.rpc.create('Welocme to solana', {
```

Comment: Thank you, i was confused to this day about this 

Answer (score 2):

so I had to import AnchorProvider and web3 from @project-serum/anchor apart from importing * as anchor.
then we set the provider as
`const provider = AnchorProvider.local()`
also change `const {SystemProgram } = anchor.web3` to  `const {SystemProgram } = web3`
and change system_program inside accounts > create rpc to systemProgram
and voila our test works!!
full test code:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { AnchorProvider, web3 } from '@project-serum/anchor';
const { SystemProgram } = web3;

describe('mycalcdapp', () => {
  const provider = AnchorProvider.local();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const calculator = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const program = anchor.workspace.Mycalcdapp;

  it('creates a calculator', async () => {
    await program.rpc.create('Welcome to solana', {
      accounts: {
        calculator: calculator.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [calculator],
    });
    const account = await program.account.calculator.fetch(
      calculator.publicKey
    );
    assert.ok(account.greeting === 'Welcome to solana');
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).